# setGridHeight auto on jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid 4.5.4.

I have a grid with a subgrid. The grid has the height set to auto but on the subGridRowExpanded event i set the height to the height of the grid plus the height of the subgrid because i don't want to use the scroll on the grid.
The problem is that when i use `$(grid).jqGrid('setGridHeight', "auto");` on the gridComplete event or on the subGridRowColapsed event and after refreshing the grid i can't see any data on the grid, the grid collapses. 
Is there any other method to set the grid height to auto?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it this way: `$(grid).parents('div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css("min-height","100px");`